# How to override function system_send_email_action_validate

Tags: 7

The following is in the core system.module

```
/**
 * Validate system_send_email_action form submissions.
 */
function system_send_email_action_validate($form, $form_state) {
  $form_values = $form_state['values'];
  // Validate the configuration form.
  if (!valid_email_address($form_values['recipient']) && strpos($form_values['recipient'], ':mail') === FALSE) {
    // We want the literal %author placeholder to be emphasized in the error message.
    form_set_error('recipient', t('Enter a valid email address or use a token e-mail address such as %author.', array('%author' => '[node:author:mail]')));
  }
}
```

This is stopping VBO send email from sending email to a CCK email field.
How can I override this function? I want to change it to the following...

```
/**
 * Validate system_send_email_action form submissions.
 */
function system_send_email_action_validate($form, $form_state) {
  $form_values = $form_state['values'];
$has_tokens = count(token_scan($form_values['recipient'])) > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
  // Validate the configuration form.
  if (!valid_email_address($form_values['recipient']) && !$has_tokens) {
    // We want the literal %author placeholder to be emphasized in the error message.
    form_set_error('recipient', t('Enter a valid email address or use a token e-mail address such as %author.', array('%author' => '[node:author:mail]')));
  }
}
```

But without hacking core. Is there a way to do this in my custom module? Im having a bit of trouble understanding how overriding a module function works, in theme functions, I can just replace the function in mt template.php using the name of my theme, however `MYMODULE_system_send_email_action` doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ["hook_preprocess_HOOK"](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7)